# window.webkitNotifications.createNotification - Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to show notification in chrome using this code:

```
var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(..params);
```

But I get this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createNotification' of undefined.

This code worked for me last week, but I'm afraid that after the latest update of Chrome is no longer working. I tried to look for maybe a new API but could not find

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently they removed the need for webkit perfix.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification)

[Demo](http://ttsvetko.github.io/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications/)

Comment: If you are using extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications

Comment: Demo is the real thing. You can use the code from the demo to support all kinds of browsers!

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround for this that I found is:

```
function show() {
  var opt = {
        type: "basic",
        title: "PriceRadar",
        message: "Item added successfully",
        iconUrl: "icon-48.png"
  };


  var notification = chrome.notifications.create('itemAdd',opt,callback);

  notification.show();

}

function callback() {

}
```

It's not the same notification banner, but it works.
Hope Google will resolve this issue

Comment: I'm not using Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Now it must be as something like this

```
var myNotification = new Notification('New Content Available', {icon: 
"some.png", body: 'Click to view'});
```

More you can read in this [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API)

Answer (score 0):

yes we had the same problem , it seems like some changes were made in the last chrome update

what i did for now was adding  a check

> if(window.webkitNotifications)

before using **window.webkitNotifications**

maybe this is just a bug an will return again soon?